# Filling remaining space in row by last element

Tags: html, css, row, markup

I have something like this:

```css
.container {
  width: 350px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    Item 1
  </div><div class="item">
    Item 2
  </div><div class="item">
    Item 3
  </div><div class="item">
    Item 4
  </div><div class="item">
    Item 5
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to get the last item fill the remaining space for itself in row. Items should be placed in sequence.

(Sorry for my Google translate...:( )

Answer (score 0):

You can use css3 [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```
.container {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
}
.container .item {
  /* This property will expand the last item to the remaining width */
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```css
.container {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 350px;
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    Item 1
  </div><div class="item">
    Item 2 Item 2 Item 2
  </div><div class="item">
    Item 3
  </div><div class="item">
    Item 4
  </div><div class="item">
    Item 5
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I forgot to mention that it is important to keep the item's wrap.:(

Comment: @user3928418 Here is another variant. [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/todo1x3y/1/);

Comment: Last element of each row must fill row to the end. (In you example items 3 and 5)

Comment: @user3928418 First fiddle is the maximum that I can offer you in this scenario.

Comment: Thank you for your desire to help, friend!